# Профайлер для Oracle/ Мониторинг запросов

Tags: oracle, profiler

Пишу приложение по работе с бд `Oracle`. При вызове хранимки результат возвращает пустой набор данных. Хотел бы посмотреть какие параметры приходят на сервер. Есть ли профайлер для `Oracle`? Раннее работал c `MS SQL` и их стандартным профайлером . Там это было гораздо удобнее. Как можно посмотреть параметры   запроса/хранимки , текст запроса идущие от приложения? Скачал себе пробную версию `Toad for Oracle`, но он как я понял включает трассировку только для своего процесса. Запросы идущие из `SQL Developer` не отображаются

.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
.

Comment: а почему бы не запускать запросы из Toad?

Comment: Если нужно ловить запросы из всех мест, то если это долгие запросы то их можно поймать в V$SESSION_LONGOPS. Если нужны не только долгие, то https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125223/show-all-queries-coming-to-an-oracle-database и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922032/creating-a-global-trigger-that-listens-to-multiple-tables/8922198#8922198